# Top-menu renderer isn't fully configured

Tags: category, error, magento-1, category-tree

I **deleted a category** from my magento installation and then i started getting this error

> "Top-menu renderer isn't fully configured."

on the page and nothing else would work.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Looks like your Codazon_Theameframework extension might break something. Try disabling it and see if the error happens again.

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at the class throwing this error `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Topmenu_Renderer` and more particularly at the function `_toHtml()` you will see the conditions required.

```
if (!$this->getTemplate() || is_null($menuTree) || is_null($childrenWrapClass)) {
    throw new Exception("Top-menu renderer isn't fully configured.");
}
```

There are 3 conditions, so 3 possibilities :

1. `!$this->getTemplate()` means your block
   `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Topmenu_Renderer` don't have any defined phtml
   template
2. `is_null($menuTree)` defined in `\Mage_Page_Block_Html_Topmenu::getHtml` means that the child block
   `catalog.topnav.renderer` does not exist
3. `is_null($childrenWrapClass)` defined in `\Mage_Page_Block_Html_Topmenu::getHtml` means that the
   `$childrenWrapClass` parameter is `null`

You need these conditions 3 conditions to be true for the menu works well.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer was really insightful. I have been able to trace this issue. I commented the function and the site was back but the categories list was no longer showing. Will have to find out what the main is.

Comment: No problem. The other issue seems to be different so can you mark this one as corrected / accepted and maybe open an other one with the other issue if you can not find how to resolve it ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is the following:

Go to

```
/app/code/local/Codazon/Themeframework/Block/Widget
```

open the file `Categoriesmenu.php`. Then find what is your Root Category id from your magento admin panel (It would be something like this Root Catalog (ID: 5)).

And at line 25 change the

```
'id_path' => 'category/2', to 'id_path' => 'category/{your_root_category_id}'
```

Answer (score 0):

i found another way to bypass this error 
**Admin > System > Configuration > Advanced > Advanced > Disable Codazon_Themeframework**

but this is just a bypass to a error because some other utilities depending like **search with category** and **facebook & twitter feed on the bottom**.

I also face the same error when i deleted one of the sub-category under root category after that i am facing this problem.