# Top-menu renderer isn't fully configured (urgent help)

Tags: error

[Top-menu renderer isn't fully configured](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/158168/top-menu-renderer-isnt-fully-configured/158170#158170?newreg=5124eb884ddd4f329d0324fcb18afff0)

[image: this is part of the image so you can take a better look]Ok, i have the same problem that is the post above, but i will explain it better:

I deleted a category in magento, after editing other products i went to the main wabsite to see how the products are shown but, now is showing me this error: "Top-menu renderer isn't fully configured.".
After finding the post that i mentioned before, i created a new root category and just move all the other categories in it, but that didn't work as i thought, then i went to the files of magento and look for `Categoriesmenu.php` and in the line 25 i edit this: `'id_path' => 'category/2',` to this `'id_path' => 'category/709',`.
709 because the new root category that i created has 709 as ID and i thought that just declaring it in that line will solve the problem, but it didn't.
I thought that i need to re-index as usual but now i go to re-index (hoping that it will re-index all urls and solve the problem) i'm not able to re-index because it get stuck in "Working" forever. 
I ended up looking how to re-index manually but the only way that i found was connecting by SSH to the server, i generate a key in the SSH section of my cPanel,  i tried using PuTTY with the key that i just create but i get an error which is "Network error: Software caused connection abort". With that happening i re-think what i should go back to find a problem with the code, but i ended up with the same problem again.

Comment: Hey Jose, I would restate that problem in a question (just edit this one) with all the information. The more information the better. Then explain what you have done and what you haven't and that the answers on that question are not solving your problem.

Comment: i just finish to edit the post

Comment: can someone help me? please :(

Comment: Please don't just dump error messages in the question form. You should at least explain
when it happens and if you did any changes before. To debug errors, follow this guide:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store